# Find most optimal algorithm for given problem

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, time-complexity, line-segment

I'm trying to solve this problem from my textbook:

> When a frisbee is thrown into a bucket, it gets stuck where the inner diameter of the bucket is smaller than the outer diameter of the frisbee. Analyse where in the bucket the frisbees gets stuck given the dimensions of the bucket and the radius of the frisbees. The bucket is always empty when a new frisbee is thrown, so they don't pile up in the bucket.
>
> The bucket is symmetric along the y-axis. The picture shows what the cross section of the bucket can look like. The walls of the bucket are line segments that always connect at origo.
>
> **Input**: (x_1,y_1),...,(x_m,y_m),r_1,...,r_n, all numbers are positive, m≤n and y_1 < y_2 < ...<y_m.
> (x_i,y_i) are the coordinates of the wall of the bucket, from the bottom to the top. r_i is the radius of the frisbee i.
>
> **Output**: h_1,...h_n, where h_1 ≤ h_2 ≤...≤ h_n
> These are the different heights (y-coordinates) where the frisbees get stuck.
> The algorithm should be as efficient as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

A lot of great algorithms have complexities that are dominated by an initial sort, so that really shouldn't set off any alarm bells for you.

Since the problem statement indicates that there are more frisbees than bucket segments, though, the complexity of O(n log n + m) that you achieve isn't quite optimal.

Note that a frisbee can only get stuck on the segment above a point that has a smaller x than all the points above it.  Start by making a list of these points in y order, which you can do easily in O(m) time.

Because every point in the list has a smaller x than all the points after it, the list is monotonically increasing in x.  For each frisbee, therefore, you can do a binary search in the list to find the last point with x < r. This takes O(log m) per frisbee for a total time of O(n log m + m), which is strictly smaller than O(n log n + m).

Comment: Since m ≤ n, you can simplify to O(n log m), which has a matching lower bound in the usual model for these problems by the usual counting argument.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat That is true. I'm not going to simplify it, though, because then your comment wouldn't make sense, and the rest of it is relevant and interesting :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how do I make sure to output the resulting y-coordinates in increasing order if the frisbees are unordered when I do the binary search? Should I use e.g. counting sort for that? @MattTimmermans

Comment: Oh, I missed that requirement.  Output in y order is also in r order, so if you have to do that, then your algorithm is optimal and you might as well sort the frisbees.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, would this solution also be optimal?: **1)** I start by sorting the frisbees in increasing order, O(n log n). **2)** Then I make the list you describe, O(m). **3)** I then do a binary search in the list to find the last point with x<r and calculate the y-coordinate, n [O(log m)+O(1)] = O(n log m).  Would the overall time complexity then be: O(n log n) + O(m) + O(n log m) = O(n log n) ? Would this also be an optimal way of doing it? Or was my original approach better?@MattTimmermans

Comment: Yes, that would also be optimal complexity, but it's more complicated for no good reason.  You don't have to do both a sort and a binary search. If you're going to sort the frisbees, then you can process the bucket segments in order.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: mh, isn't O(n log n) worse than O(n log m) ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, but it turns out that the output needs to be in frisbee size order, so O(n log m) isn't possible.

Comment: You are right, I missed that.

Comment: Is this a greedy algorithm? @MattTimmermans

Answer (score 0):

The worst case is when every frisbee lands on a different segment, and that's possible if `m = n` and if, for all `j` and `i` such that `0 < j < i`, `x_j < x_i`. From there, the problem amounts to sorting the list of frisbees. So the complexity of the solution is indeed dominated by the sorting.

However, the complexity of sorting isn't necessarily `O(n log n)`. If the maximum size of a frisbee has a limit `l`, and if `l < n`, then using radix sort will lower the complexity to `O(n log l)` (where `log l` is the number of digits of `l` or "key length").